# Consolidate IF/Else Series

Tags: javascript

I have the following series of If/Else statement which all do the same if the variable value is greater than 0 Then set the related field value to TRUE.  Is this the only way to do this in a series or perhaps is there a more efficient method.

```
if(tvEx > 0){
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_tvtun','T');      
    }else{
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_tvtun','F');
    }
    if(widEx > 0){
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_wdscrbnr','T');       
    }else{
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_wdscrbnr','F');
    }
    if(corEx > 0){
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_corex','T');      
    }else{
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_corex','F');
    }
    if(weatherEx > 0){
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_weather','T');        
    }else{
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_weather','F');
    }
    if(vidEx > 0){
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_vidcontr','T');       
    }else{
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_vidcontr','F');
    }
    if(myHd > 0){
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_myhd','T');       
    }else{
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_myhd','F');
    }
    if(newSight > 0){
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_new3d','T');      
    }else{
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_new3d','F');
    }
    if(qEx > 0){
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_queue','T');      
    }else{
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_queue','F');
    }
```

Comment: A `for-loop` or `foreach loop` would clean this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this through a loop:

```
var variables= [tvEx, widEx, corEx, weatherEx, vidEx, myHd, newSight, qEx],
    fields = ['tvtun', 'wdscrbnr', 'corex', 'weather', 'vidcontr', 'myhd', 'new3d', 'queue'];

for (var i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
  var field = 'custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_' + fields[i],
      value = variables[i] > 0 ? 'T' : 'F';

  nlapiSetFieldValue(field, value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was a great option.   I think the JSON would have worked just as well but I felt this was a little cleaner.   I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a JSON object containing an array of your variable names combined with the value:

```
var array = [
    {
        name:"tvEx",
        value:4
    },
    etc...
]
```

Now you can iterate over this array and on every item you can test your if/else statement. When calling `nlapiSetValue()` you can do something like:

```
nlapiSetValue('custrecord_nsx_lic_ds_' + array[i].name, 'T')
```